# fadeIn() selector not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transition, fade

I have a page in which I want to fade in and out a `div` when a link is clicked. Below is a simplified version of the webpage.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fading.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="transition">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.php" class="transition">blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pharetra dictum magna nec eleifend. Curabitur malesuada mauris suscipit purus euismod ultricies et id ipsum. Praesent sagittis in justo nec ultricies. Vivamus in lectus ac sem varius consequat. Integer pretium augue sit amet tempus mollis. Maecenas massa magna, bibendum nec quam a, eleifend congue diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The script `fading.js` acts by fading in and out `#content` to smoothen the transition between pages.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').css("display", "none");
    $('#content').fadeIn(800);
    $('a.transition').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $('#content').fadeOut(800, redirectPage);       
    });
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Surprisingly, it works like a charm on Safari 7, but fails on Chrome. The selector `#content` does not seem to work, resulting in the whole `body` (including `menu`) getting faded in and out whenever an event occur.

I am wondering why this is the case. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jquery?

Comment: Yes the fiddle shows this working fine http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/cx2C6/ using jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: You can use jquery.ui too!

Comment: @DominicTobias, that's a very good question actually. I just changed it to code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js, but the issue remains.

Comment: @iHubble Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: The effect is the same as @RobSchmuecker, except on the whole document. Replacing `#content` by `body` gives [my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/cx2C6/1/), but my code is identical to Rob.

Comment: No wonder! You're fading the `body` in your example?!  That's why the body *is* fading!

Comment: Please read carefully. My code has `#content`, not `body`! But the resulting effect is *as if* it was `body`. I don't know how to reproduce a problem in JSFiddle that is browser-specific...

Comment: Clearing my browsing data and restarting Apache seemed to have resolve the problem. Never happened to me before. Weird... Thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: @iHubble your referenced demo http://jsfiddle.net/cx2C6/1/ *is* using `body` however?  I am using my fiddle produced above : http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/cx2C6/ which uses the `#content` selector and works fine on my version of Chrome?

Comment: To avoid repeated DOM queries I would be extremely tempted to cache the jQuery object by storing it in a variable, something like - *var $content = $('#content'); $content.css("display", "none");* This variable would then by used for the three interactions with this element.